Reproducing Transmission Spectrum from Photonic Crystal Paper (Transmittance Peak Issue)
I’m working on a project where I’m trying to reproduce the transmission spectra of a one-dimensional photonic crystal (PhC) with a defect layer, based on a research paper. In the paper, they show the transmittance reaching a peak value of 1. The PhC consists of alternating layers of silicon (Si) and silicon dioxide (SiO₂), and the defect layer is pure water.
The paper I'm referring to is titled "Detection of Waterborne Bacteria Using Photonic Crystal" and includes a graph (Figure 2) that I’m specifically trying to replicate. This graph plots the transmission spectra for N = 10 layers with a 1D water defect layer. The design wavelength used is 1700 nm.
Here’s a link to the paper for reference: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gsNv84mjuQRGXiy_G_5_ruiuHQxvV4kc/view?usp=sharing
Thanks in advance for any help!
clc;
clear all;
close all;
n_Si = 3.465;    
n_SiO2 = 1.442;  
n_water = 1.333; 

lambda_design = 1700; 
d_Si = lambda_design / (4 * n_Si);   
d_SiO2 = lambda_design / (4 * n_SiO2);
d_defect = d_Si + d_SiO2; 

lambda_range = linspace(1100, 2750, 6603); 
N = 10;% Number of periods


transmittance = arrayfun(@(lambda) transfer_matrix_method(lambda, N, n_Si, n_SiO2, n_water, d_Si, d_SiO2, d_defect), lambda_range);

% (Figure 2(a))
figure;
plot(lambda_range, transmittance, 'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('Wavelength (nm)');
ylabel('Transmittance');
title('Transmittance Spectrum for N = 10, d_d = 1D with Pure Water Defect Layer');
grid on;


function T = transfer_matrix_method(lambda, N, n_Si, n_SiO2, n_defect, d_Si, d_SiO2, d_defect)
    n_air = 1; % Refractive index of air
    n_substrate = 1.517; % Refractive index of substrate (glass)

    M_total = eye(2);
    
    for i = 1:N/2
        delta_Si = 2 * pi * n_Si * d_Si / lambda;
        M_Si = [cos(delta_Si), 1i * sin(delta_Si) / n_Si; 1i * n_Si * sin(delta_Si), cos(delta_Si)];
        
        delta_SiO2 = 2 * pi * n_SiO2 * d_SiO2 / lambda;
        M_SiO2 = [cos(delta_SiO2), 1i * sin(delta_SiO2) / n_SiO2; 1i * n_SiO2 * sin(delta_SiO2), cos(delta_SiO2)];
        
        M_total = M_Si * M_SiO2 * M_total;
    end
    
    delta_defect = 2 * pi * n_defect * d_defect / lambda;
    M_defect = [cos(delta_defect), 1i * sin(delta_defect) / n_defect; 1i * n_defect * sin(delta_defect), cos(delta_defect)];
    
    M_total = M_total * M_defect * M_total;
    
    A = M_total(1,1);
    B = M_total(1,2);
    C = M_total(2,1);
    D = M_total(2,2);
   
    T = (4 * n_air * n_substrate) / abs(A * n_substrate + B + C * n_air * n_substrate + D * n_air)^2;
end

Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I set up the quarter-wave condition for the thicknesses of Si and SiO₂ layers.
I applied the transfer matrix method to compute the transmittance.
My transmittance pattern looks correct, but the peak value is only reaching 0.84 instead of 1.

Refractive indices:
Si: 3.465
SiO₂: 1.442
Water (defect): 1.333
Air: 1
Substrate: 1.517 (glass)
Thicknesses:
Si: quarter-wave at 1700 nm
SiO₂: quarter-wave at 1700 nm
Water defect: sum of the Si and SiO₂ thicknesses (1D defect layer)
Wavelength range: 1100 nm to 2750 nm
Problem:
The transmittance spectrum pattern is correct, but the maximum value is 0.84. According to the paper, it should reach 1.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to adjust the formula or approach so that the transmittance peak reaches 1?
The image shows the original plot vs what I got:


What happens if you increase the number of sample points in lambda_range, especially in the region of 1848? The regions where your values differ look like they have very high rates of change, could it be that you've narrowly missed the value which would give the exact peak from the paper?

I just ran the program with increased sample points in lambda_range = linspace(1100, 2750, 6603000); 
this time in the region of 1848 the peak value is 0.844744
